# Avoid recursion with RxJS5 observables

Tags: recursion, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

Okay, so I would like to avoid recursion with observables, using a combination of external and internal events instead of recalling the same method/function.

Right now I have this:

```
Queue.prototype.deq = function (opts) {

    opts = opts || {};

    const noOfLines = opts.noOfLines || opts.count || 1;
    const isConnect = opts.isConnect !== false;

    let $dequeue = this.init()
        .flatMap(() => {
            return acquireLock(this)
                .flatMap(obj => {
                    if(obj.error){

                    // if there is an error acquiring the lock we
                    // retry after 100 ms, which means using recursion
                    // because we call "this.deq()" again

                        return Rx.Observable.timer(100)
                            .flatMap(() => this.deq(opts));
                    }
                    else{
                        return makeGenericObservable()
                          .map(() => obj);
                    }
                })

        })
        .flatMap(obj => {
            return removeOneLine(this)
                .map(l => ({l: l, id: obj.id}))
        })
        .flatMap(obj => {
            return releaseLock(this, obj.id)
                .map(() => obj.l)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error(e.stack || e);
            return releaseLock(this);
        });

    if (isConnect) {
        $dequeue = $dequeue.publish();
        $dequeue.connect();
    }

    return $dequeue;

};
```

instead of the above, which uses recursion (hopefully correctly), I'd like to use a more evented approach. If there is an error passed back from the acquireLock function, I would like to retry every 100ms, as soon as it succeeds I want to stop, I am not sure how to do this, and it's difficult for me to test it....is this about right?

```
Queue.prototype.deq = function (opts) {

    // ....

    let $dequeue = this.init()
        .flatMap(() => {
            return acquireLock(this)
                .flatMap(obj => {
                    if(obj.error){
                        return Rx.Observable.interval(100)
                            .takeUntil(
                                acquireLock(this)
                                .filter(obj => !obj.error)
                            )
                    }
                    else{

                        // this is just an "empty" observable
                        // which immediately fires onNext()

                        return makeGenericObservable()
                              .map(() => obj);
                    }
                })

        })

     // ...

    return $dequeue;

};
```

Is there a way to make that more concise? I also would like to only retry 5 times or so. My primary question is - *How can I also create a count alongside the interval, so that every 100 ms I retry, until either the lock is acquired or a count reaches 5?*

I need something like this:

```
.takeUntil(this or that)
```

perhaps I can simply chain the takeUntils, like so:

```
                   return Rx.Observable.interval(100)
                    .takeUntil(
                        acquireLock(this)
                        .filter(obj => !obj.error)
                    )
                    .takeUntil(++count < 5);
```

I could do this:

```
                return Rx.Observable.interval(100)
                    .takeUntil(
                        acquireLock(this)
                        .filter(obj => !obj.error)
                    )
                    .takeUntil( Rx.Observable.timer(500));
```

But probably looking for something a little less kludgy

But I don't know where to (store / keep track of) the `count` variable...

Also looking to make this more concise and possibly check it for correctness.

I have to say, if this stuff works, it's very powerful coding constructs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two operators that can help you: [retry](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry) and [retryWhen](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen). The both resubscribe on source observable an thus retry the failed operation.

Check this example where we have an observable that fails on first `count` subscriptions:

```js
let getObs = (count) => {
  return Rx.Observable.create((subs) => {
    console.log('Subscription count = ', count);

    if(count) {
      count--;
      subs.error("ERROR");
    } else {
      subs.next("SUCCESS");
      subs.complete();
    }
  
    return () => {};
  });
};

getObs(2).subscribe(console.log, console.log);
getObs(2).retry(2).subscribe(console.log, console.log);
getObs(3).retry(2).subscribe(console.log, console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see:

- If we call it as it is it will fail
- With `retry` we can, well, retry it several times and пуе success response
- If observable fails too many tomes `retry` will give up and propagate error along the chain.

What you actually need is `retryWhen` because `retry` tries to perform operation again without delay.

```js
let getObs = (count) => {
  return Rx.Observable.create((subs) => {
    if(count) {
      count--;
      subs.error("ERROR");
    } else {
      subs.next("SUCCESS");
      subs.complete();
    }
  
    return () => {};
  });
};

getObs(2).retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(100))
  .subscribe(console.log, console.log);
getObs(4).retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(100))
  .subscribe(console.log, console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

It's easy to add a delay with `retryWhen` but force it to fail after number of attempts is harder:

```js
let getObs = (count) => {
  return Rx.Observable.create((subs) => {
    if(count) {
      count--;
      subs.error("ERROR");
    } else {
      subs.next("SUCCESS");
      subs.complete();
    }
  
    return () => {};
  });
};

getObs(2)
  .retryWhen(errors => {
    return errors.delay(100).scan((errorCount, err) => {
      if(!errorCount) {
        throw err;
      }
      return --errorCount;
    }, 2);
  })
  .subscribe(console.log, console.log);

getObs(4)
  .retryWhen(errors => {
    return errors.delay(100).scan((errorCount, err) => {
      if(!errorCount) {
        throw err;
      }
      return --errorCount;
    }, 2);
  })
  .subscribe(console.log, console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

And finally, both retries expect error to be thrown so you need to do this when acquiring lock:

```
    .flatMap(() => {
        return acquireLock(this)
            .switchMap(obj => {
              if(obj.error) {
                return Rx.Observable.throw(obj.error);
              } else {
                Rx.Observable.of(obj);
              }
            })
            .retryWhen(...)
    })
```